# How can I build the best Cyber Cafe possible using Ubuntu (Desktop or the Server Edition)?

Tags: server, system-installation

My question has to do with my plan/dream of opening a Cyber Cafe in Mogadishu, Somalia, my birth place. I plan to use 5 to 15 computers (all laptops) running Ubuntu. 
Now that you have the background to my question, I need your help, advice and expertise.

1. What type of computer (laptop) should I use for this project?
2. What type of operating system (Ubuntu Desktop/Ubuntu Server Edition) should I use?
3. How can I setup a file and printer sharing server?
4. What program should I use to manage the client computers?

If you have done this before and can point me to the best and easiest way to build this Cyber Cafe, I would appreciate it tremendously.
Also, if you can point me to any books, articles, or blogs which I should read, I would appreciate it too.

Comment: Search for "ubuntu kiosk" on google as a starter ;)

Comment: Or if you do not want to re-create the wheel, use a distro built and maintained for this purpose.

Comment: And a reborn card might be very efficient: cost around 18 euro and when you reboot this card resets the system to a pre defined state.

Comment: You could look into getting computers without hard drives to save money! And just boot them from a Server, if you did a live OS, perhaps a customized Ubuntu LiveOS, it would automatically be a "fresh OS" after each boot. Very good for security in that situation as nothing gets saved by users.

Comment: Are you thinking of a Gaming Cafe? or just Internet Access web browsing, simple stuff? Gaming Rigs cost big $$ but can build culture, IMO your better off doing just simple Web Browsing though, lower risk higher ROI

Comment: Broad, open-ended questions like this one are unsuitable for the question & answer format of StackExchange sites like AskUbuntu and therefore off topic. A much better place for them is [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/).